# MySql/JAVA REPLACE

Tags: java, mysql

I have one problem, when I want change the content in data base from java with this metod:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE contentPage1 SET Content = REPLACE(Content,'"+oldContenido+"','"+newContenido+"');");
```

I cant change the content because i want input new text, and this text contains characters like ,`' I cant change the old content! What I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you get any errors? What errors? Could you give us an example string?

Comment: You should look into [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). They allow you to use placeholders in your SQL and then fill out the values later. They handle all the escaping of special characters automatically!

Comment: @JesseWebb - You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @TedHopp - I couldn't tell if that comment would actually help out the OP or not cause the question was worded awkwardly. I posted as an answer though anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). You can add your parameters *to the statement* object and it will take care for you to properly handle any character escaping, type conversions, &c.

Edit: Jesse Web is right and has provided an example solution. His answer should be accepted.

Comment: This is completely ignoring the issue of OP trying to do regex replacements in the database.

Comment: The OP did not state anything about regexps.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Where did you get the idea that OP is doing regex replacements?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - MySQL's [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) statement has nothing to do with Java's `String.replace()` method. It's not a regex operation in any way.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - It happens; no worries. However, if you're the downvoter on this answer, I suggest you remove the downvote. :)

Comment: I will try delete and then input the new content. I thing it's a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

[PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) allow you to use placeholders characters (?) in your SQL and fill in the values later. They also handle escaping automatically...

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE contentPage1 SET Content = REPLACE(Content, ?, ?);");
pstmt.setString(1, "first");
pstmt.setString(2, "second - characters like ' will be escaped automatically!");
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments below, it sounds like the OP isn't actually trying to use the REPLACE SQL function, they are simply trying to update the data in a given column. Here is some sample code to achieve this (slightly modified version of @TedHopp's comment):

```
int messageId = 123; // use the PK or unique identifier of the record you want to update
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE contentPage1 SET Content = ? WHERE Id = ?;"); // 'Id' is whatever your PK column is
pstmt.setString(1, "my new message content");
pstmt.setInt(2, messageId);
int numRowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I will try delete and then input the new datas. Is it a good approach?

Comment: If your new text includes those 'unwanted' characters too, this will not help in any way. - But you can of course use the `PreparedStatement` for `delete`s and `insert`s, too :)

Comment: @SteffanPetrov - It's not going to address the problem that your content has special characters that need to be escaped. The problem is not your use of `REPLACE`; it's that a quote mark in the data destroys the syntax of the entire SQL statement.

Comment: @Ted Hopp-Tell me please, what can I do? I must finish with my homework very soon.

Comment: @SteffanPetrov - I don't understand your problem. Can you update your question with any new details you may have. Please describe in detail what you are trying and how it is failing to do what you want.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - I created one blog, and in this blog I've many messages. There is edit button in each message. When I try change the contains in one message I must change to and the contains in MySql. When I try to replace oldContent with newContent the program do nothing. If  There are another content without characters like ;,. etc.. I can change it.

Comment: @SteffanPetrov - create a prepared statement for the following SQL: `UPDATE contentPage1 SET Content = ? WHERE Content = ?`. Then run `prep.setString(1, `newContenido);` and `prep.setString(2, oldContenido);` to bind the arguments. This will interpolate the values in `oldContenido` and `newContenido` into the statement with properly escaped special characters. Then you can call `prep.executeUpdate();` to make the change.

Comment: @SteffanPetrov - I have updated the answer to reflect what we discussed in these comments.